# Как сделать, чтобы из папки выдавались все фотографии, а не случайная?

Tags: python

```
img_list23 = ['img_list43/ocr.jpg', 'img_list43/ocr1.jpg', 'img_list43/ocr2.jpg']
img_path = random.choice(img_list23)
await message.answer_photo(photo=open(img_path, "rb"))
```

Comment: пишу бота и не могу понять как сделать что бы из папки он отправлял все фото а не рандом

Comment: Добавляйте все уточнения прямо в вопрос - кнопка "править".

Answer (score 0):

Рандомное фото достается из функции random.choice(img_list23), уберите ее и переберите массив

```py
img_list23 = ['img_list43/ocr.jpg', 'img_list43/ocr1.jpg', 'img_list43/ocr2.jpg']
for image in img_list23:
    await message.answer_photo(photo=open(image, "rb"))
```